# Remove all links starting with www, http, and links like example.com from string using Regex

Tags: regex

I have a string and I want to do the following:

1. Remove all links starting with http, https, www
2. Remove links like `example.com`, `example.net` and `example.us` , also `example.com/foo`. And `example.com` could be a different website.
3. I want to keep decimals like 3.14.

I am not a professional in Regex, but I tried following expression:

```
http[^\s]+|www[^\s]+
```

It work with http, https and www. Now I am stuck with example.com etc....

Thanks.

Example

**Input:**

This is text **http://www.example.com** **https://www.example.com** **www.example.com** **example.com** **example.us** **example.us/test** This is text 3.14

**Output:**

This is text This is text 3.14

Comment: show the input text and the expected output

Comment: Updated with example

Comment: What about `example.com/foo`?

Comment: yes, and this one too. Didn't think about it, thanks. Question is updated

Comment: There are different flavors of regex. What programming language are you using? If it's a language that doesn't have built-in regexes, what regex library are you using?

Comment: I am using c#..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
[^\s\d]+\.[^\s\d]+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ytnlf/3)**

Comment: this will remove all decimals as well like 3.14

Comment: @IgorLevashov, fixed, check it now

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one, replace this:

```
(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6}) ?
```

by nothing.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/HmwSea/4

Few useful regexes with URL: [8 Regular Expressions You Should Know](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149)

Comment: You have to clarify it in your question. Answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.\w+ ?
```

with nothing

Note that this will not work on urls like `irc.example.com` for that use:

```
(https?:\/\/)?(\w\.)*\w+\.\w+ ?
```

However, these regrexs matches all words with . in them for example `13.34`. (but not `Mr.`) so be careful.

(Based on streetturtle's code)